# Google Maps intersections not working

Tags: json, maps

It seems like Google Maps isn't returning intersections anymore. When I type 147th and Broadway, I only see "Broadway" as a return. This looks like a sudden change as of this morning. Anyone else experiencing this or know of any solution to get intersections back?

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Broadway",
               "short_name" : "Broadway",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "New York",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New York",
               "short_name" : "NY",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Broadway, New York, NY, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 40.8264107,
               "lng" : -73.95035679999999
            },
            "location_type" : "GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 40.8277596802915,
                  "lng" : -73.94900781970848
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 40.8250617197085,
                  "lng" : -73.9517057802915
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "EhtCcm9hZHdheSwgTmV3IFlvcmssIE5ZLCBVU0E",
         "types" : [ "intersection" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a year old, but in case anyone else is looking for an answer (as I was)...

You can increase the probability of Google returning an intersection by providing one or both of the following in the address parameter of your query string:

1. Street types (a.k.a. street suffixes)
   For example, rather than:

address=Main+%26+Stewart

provide:

address=Main+**St**+%26+Stewart+**Ave**

2. Provide the city, state or zip code (or all of these) where the intersection is located.  For example, *even without street suffixes* but with the town name, Google will return the correct intersection for:

address=main+%26+stewart,**+huntington**

As a side note, although providing bounds in the query is helpful, it does not guarantee that results will be limited to that area.  Per Google:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Viewports

"Note that biasing only prefers results within the bounds; if more relevant results exist outside of these bounds, they may be included."

Hope this is helpful...